# Why is my elif statement not working Python 3?

Tags: python

I'm making a simple life sim but on line 10-15 my elif statement is not working you have to input cry 2 times instead of 1

```
def p(words):
  print(words)
  return words

p("Hello I'm Bob You Will Be Controlling My Life From Now On")
print ("Side Note DON'T DIE")
print ("Anyways Bye")
print (":)")
print ("You Are Born On Monday The Fourth Of March Would You Like  To start To cry or stay quite")
if input() == "cry":
  print ("You Cry For The Rest Of Your Life And Die Of Depression At The Age Of 12 YOU DIED RE-RUN THE PROGRAM")
  exit()
elif input() == "stay quite":
  p("----------------------")
  print ("You Stay Quiet And Your Mother Is Very Confeused Mother: Why Are You So Quiet?. You Fell Asleep And Woke Up The Next Day At 2:34 AM")
print ("do you want to go to sleep or dance")

print ("go to sleep|dance")
if input() == "dance":
  print ("You dance For The Rest Of Your Life And die from exhaustion YOU DIED RE-RUN THE PROGRAM")
  exit()
else:
  print ("You Go To Sleep And the next day you Wake Up you open your eyes to people looking at you and saying aww look at that cute little baby") 
  print ("You have the choice to either make some baby noises or tell them to go away and go to sleep")
  print ("go away or make some baby noises")
  if input() == "go away":
    print ("you dumb baby you cant talk")
  else: 
    print ("Everyone: Awwwwwww! You Are So Cute Bartholomew Bobbity Bob")
print ("after this you decide to go to sleep or go to the roof to paraglide")
print ("go to sleep or go to the roof")
if input() == "go to the roof":
  print ("You go to the roof and paraglide and you come closer and closer to the ground and you see a bird and the bird saves you and you go home and      live to tell the tale")
else:
  print ("you had a nightmare and died from fright")
```

I'm new to Python so I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Can't reproduce. If I run the code above, I enter "cry" and it quits with the expected message

Answer (score 2):

Consider what you're doing here:

```
if input() == "cry":
    #do something
elif input() == "stay quite":
    #do something else
```

How would you get to the `elif` block?  Since `input()` prompts for input, you'd need to enter the value `"stay quite"` *twice*, because you're calling `input()` *twice*.

Prompt for input *once* and store the result in a variable.  For example:

```
choice = input()
if choice == "cry":
    #do something
elif choice == "stay quite":
    #do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the input to a variable and then run the if/else on that variable.  You will see that the code works.

```
user_input = input()
if user_input == "cry":
  print ("You Cry For The Rest Of Your Life And Die Of Depression At The Age Of 12 YOU DIED RE-RUN THE PROGRAM")
  exit()
elif user_input == "stay quite":
    p("----------------------")
    print ("You Stay Quiet And Your Mother Is Very Confeused Mother: Why Are You So Quiet?. You Fell Asleep And Woke Up The Next Day At 2:34 AM")
```